# PHP in_array result not as expected in IP Address allowed case

Tags: php

I'm using array to allow IP Address who can access, but got wrong result when query it with database.

```
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP[] = array($dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
}

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowedIP))
{
    $ip = 1;
}
else
{
    $ip = 0;
}

echo $ip;
```

The result is always 0 even my IP Address(192.168.183.28) including in the list.

When I `print_r($allowedIP)` the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 192.168.184.20, 192.168.184.15 ) )
```

It should be got result 1, because my IP Address is in the list of array.

Is there any trick how to do that?

Comment: You have an array containing arrays of comma separated strings. `in_array` is not going to find a string inside a string inside an array.

Comment: you should flatten your array first, take a look https://www.cowburn.info/2012/03/17/flattening-a-multidimensional-array-in-php/

Comment: @deceze Let me know how to do the trick

Comment: change `$allowedIP[] = array($dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);` to `$allowedIP[] = array_merge($allowedIP, array_map('trim', explode(',', $dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS'])));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will check the value of the array, in your case it have multiple IP addresses in string format in array values.

Change

```
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP[] = array($dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
}
```

To

```
$allowedIP = array();
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP = array_merge($allowedIP, array_map('trim', explode(',', $dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS'])));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like `$dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']` contains strings like `'192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28'`, which you're then stuffing into arrays in an array. `in_array` is not going to discover strings in strings in arrays. You need to make one flat array of all those individual addresses first:

```
while ($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile)) {
    $ips = array_map('trim', explode(',', $dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']));
    $allowedIP = array_merge($allowedIP, $ips);
}
```

Now you have one flat list of IPs which `in_array` can search through.

However, since you're pulling those IPs from a database in the first place, you should probably do a simple database query instead of building and searching through this array in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIps = explode(', ',  $dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
    foreach($allowedIps as $singleAllowedIp)
    {
        $allowedIP[] = $singleAllowedIp;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```html
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP[] = array($dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

test this code:

```
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP[] = array($dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
}
if([[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]]==$allowedIP)
{
    $ip = 1;
}
else
{
    $ip = 0;
}

echo $ip;
```